# How to combine a strings and store it in a array after using strtok() from a "full string" in C

Tags: c

Im a new learner of C and i got trouble combining the strings which separated by strtok().
Using Clion (C99)
Lets have a look at my codes.

```
char recipient[30];
char final_destination[50];
char status[10];


printf("Please enter 1> Recipient-, 2> Final Destination- and 
3>Delivery status :\n");    Entered(L-Rat Kitchen-House Not-Arrived)

scanf("%29s%49s%9s", recipient, final_destination, status);
```

///*only recipient first*///The purpose of storing "recipient final_destination, status" in a string is because to let user input data in a same line while using **scanf** .After that, i use strtok to separate those words before/after "-" .Separate different string by using the spacebar in scanf  which prevents data input like (L-ratKitchenHouseNot-arrive).

```
const char s[] = "-";
char *token;
token = strtok(recipient, s);
while( token != NULL )
 ???????????????????????

token = strtok(NULL, s);
```

At the line of ?????????????? , im stuck , i dont know how or is there a way to put those processed data in a array and combine it.

Expecting:

Input: (L-Rat House-Kitchen Not-Arrive)

Output: (L Rat House Kitchen Not Arrive)

Would be very helpful if theres a solution !!!

Comment: Do you just want to replace dash with space in the last string? No need to use strtok for that!

Comment: @hyde how? how to replace it ?

Comment: Just use for loop over the string, and replace any characters you want. Though better solution would be to change the scanf format string so that the last item would be everything until the end of the line, so user could actually enter spaces in the last field.

Answer (score 1):

try this, if you want store tokens in an array.

```
while (token != NULL) 
    { 
        printf("%s\n", token); 
        token = strtok(NULL, "-"); 
    }
```

Comment: "*tokens in an array*" which "array" please?

Comment: @alk Nothing I just meant instead of just printing it.